# Load every X result in different div

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have this html structure:

```
<div id="content" class="container">

  <div class="item">
     <img src="image" alt="" />
  </div>  
</div>
```

And I load images into this div - `item`like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE album = ? ORDER BY image_id DESC");
$stmt->execute(array($album_id));
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($data as $row)
{                                                    
    echo '
          <div class="item">
              <img src="'.$row['image_path'].'" alt="" />
          </div>';        
}
```

My question is it possible to add second div in foreach loop and place every 3rd image into it. Like this:

```
<div id="content" class="container">

  <div class="item">
     <img src="image" alt="" />
  </div>  
 <div class="third-item">
     <img src="image" alt="" />
  </div> 
</div>
```

Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Keep a counter in the `foreach` and then do something like `if($counter % 3 == 0)` and change the div name if true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE album = ? ORDER BY image_id DESC");
$stmt->execute(array($album_id));
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
$i = 0;
$res="";
foreach ($data as $row)
{                                                    
    $res.='
      <div class="item">
          <img src="'.$row['image_path'].'" alt="" />
      </div>';        
    if ($i % 3 == 0)
    {
       $res.='<div class="third-item">
          <img src="'.$row['image_path'].'" alt="" />
      </div>'; 
    }
    $i++;
}  

echo $res;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a loop increment variable and use the modulus operator like this:

```
my $i = 0;
foreach ($data as $row)
{                                                    
    echo '
      <div class="item">
          <img src="'.$row['image_path'].'" alt="" />
      </div>';        
    if ($i % 3 == 0)
    {
     echo '<div class="third-item">
          <img src="'.$row['image_path'].'" alt="" />
      </div>'; 
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: add echo in if condition also.

Answer (score 1):

hello my friend you can use tow inner loops like this :

```
    <?PHP
echo '<div id="content" class="container">';

for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
echo '<div id="content" class="container">';
    for ($j=0; $j < 3 ; $j++) {
        if($j == 2){
            echo ' <div class="third-item">';
            echo '<img src="image" alt="" />';
            echo '</div>';
        }else {
            echo '  <div class="item">';

            echo '<img src="image" alt="" />';
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}
echo "</div>";
```